# MongoDb remove operation among multiple collection

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to create simple javascript program which removes untagged images from mongoDb collection.

1. I am having 2 collections names `albums` and `images`
2. data in each collection will be about 1 million records per collection.
3. sample data for `albums` collection will be like `{ "_id" : 0, "images" : [ 2433, 2753, 2983, 6510, 11375, 12974]}`
4. sample data in `images` collection will be like `{ "_id" : 61782, "height" : 480, "width" : 640, "tags" : [ "cats", "work" ] }`
5. I have created following javascript code but for some reason it is giving `imageList.image` is `undefined` error.

   ```
   var albumImages = db.albums.aggregate([{$unwind:"$images"},{$group:_id:null,image:{$addToSet:"$images"}}}]);
   var imageList = db.images.aggregate([{$group: {_id:null, image:{$addToSet:"$_id"}} }]);
   for(var i = 0; i < imageList.image.length; i++) {
       if(albumImages.image.indexOf(imageList.image[i]) < 0) {
           db.images.removeOne({_id:imageList.image[i]});
       }
   }
   ```

Here I want to remove all the items from images which are not part of any album.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: if imagelist contains image then push image into new array and do a for loop on that

Comment: Your javascript code seems to have several syntax errors (e.g. missing open-brace after `$group:` in the first line, e.g. only part of the required $addToSet construct present) - is this really the code you are running?